# aws glue JDBC connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, aws-glue

It seems that AWS Glue "Add Connection" can only add connections specific to only one database. I have to connect all databases from MS SQL server. Is it possible to cover multiple databases in one Aws Glue "Add Connection" or we need new connection for every new database.

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC connection string is limited to one database at a time.

From glue's documentation:

***For JDBC to connect to the data store, a db_name in the data store is required. The db_name is used to establish a network connection with the supplied username and password. When connected, AWS Glue can access other databases in the data store to run a crawler or run an ETL job.***

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-connections.html?icmpid=docs_glue_console

Answer (score 0):

The database name is part of jdbc url. As you can have only one url in a glue connection you can only point to one database. But you can still use all the schema under the database.